# Elegant way to stringify keys with Rails and Mongo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

If you supply Mongo with a hash that uses symbols as keys and save the document, it will 'stringify' it, meaning the keys will be converted to strings. To summarize:

```
condition:                       hash keys will be:
----------                       ------------------
after initializing a document    symbols or strings
after saving a document          strings
after fetching a document        strings
```

This 'asymmetry' has led to some ugliness in my tests. I would like to be able to 'rely on' the keys always being strings - and not worry about if the document has just been initialized or not.

What are one or more elegant ways to avoid this?

Note: In my case, I'm using Mongoid, but I don't think this question is necessarily Mongoid specific. It probably applies to any Rails project that uses MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines could work. Basically this code redefines Mongoid's `field` macro (its setter).

```
require 'mongoid'

module Stringifier
  def field name, args = {}
    super # call mongoid implementation

    define_method "#{name}=" do |val|
      val.stringify_keys! if val && val.respond_to?(:stringify_keys!)
      super(val)
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document
  extend Stringifier

  field :subhash, type: Hash
end

f = Foo.new
f.subhash = {a: 1, b: 2}

puts f.subhash
# >> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
```

This may not be the cleanest implementation, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. (Suggestion: it would probably be smart to check if the field type (`:type`) is `Hash` before defining the new setter method.)

Comment: Yes, it's up to you to improve this code. I gave you the idea, my job is done :)

Answer (score 1):

My current solution is to override each field setter to call `stringify_keys!`. For example:

```
def field_name=(x)
  x.stringify_keys! if x
  super(x)
end
```

This it the best I've found so far. I considered other alternatives:

- Using a [`before_validation`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) callback. However, I don't like this approach. I didn't like having to call `valid?` in order to trigger stringification.
- Using [`after_initialize`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#after_initialize-and-after_find). However, this doesn't handle the case of calling a setter after initialization.

Comment: You could redefine `field` macro.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That sounds worthy of an independent answer :)